# Light on color sensor is blue

Tags: ev3, lighting, sensor-colour

We had the sensor color on red and it was working with our remote.  We changed the batteries in the 'brain' and now the light sensor is blue and won't work with the remote.  Any suggestions? It's a mindstorm EV3 sensor.

Answer (score 3):

The color of the LED on the LEGO EV3 Color Sensor depends on which mode it is in.

From the EV3 help file:

> **COLOR MODE**
>
> [image]
>
> When the Color Sensor is in Color mode, red, green, and blue LED lights on the front of the sensor will turn on.
>
> **REFLECTED LIGHT INTENSITY MODE**
>
> [image]
>
> When the Color Sensor is in Reflected Light Intensity mode, a red LED light on the front of the sensor will turn on.
>
> **AMBIENT LIGHT INTENSITY MODE**
>
> [image]
>
> In Ambient Light Intensity mode, a blue LED light on the front of the sensor will turn on dimly.

If you want the LED to be red, make sure you are using the Reflected Light Intensity Mode in your program.

If you are doing this and the LED still does not turn red, you should contact LEGO MINDSTORMS customer support.